# How to fix webpack resolve-url-loader not working?

Tags: webpack, path, resolution, resolve-url-loader

**Resolve-url-loader** is not resolving **images/fonts** in my **css files.** My folder structure is like this:

```
src 
   public
      images
           -banner-bg.jpg
      stylesheets
         css
           -basic.css with background: url(../../images/banner-bg.jpg)
         scss
           -main.scss with @import "../css/basic.css";
```

The output folders:

```
dist
  public
     images
           -banner-bg.jpg
     stylesheets
           -main-output.css
```

The images & fonts diplay ok in dev server and are correctly copied in production. The **main-output.css** - when examined - shows

`background:url(public/images/banner-bg.jpg`

instead of the expected

`background:url(../images/banner-bg.jpg)`

And the browser console shows the error:

GET file:///home/ustrd/Documents/myproject12/dist/ **public/stylesheets/public/images/** banner-bg.jpg net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

```
plugins: [
   new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
     filename: path.join("public", "stylesheets", "[name].css")
   })
 ],
 module: {
   rules: [
     {
       test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
       use: [
         MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 
         {
           loader: "css-loader",
           options: {
             sourceMap: true,
             importLoaders: 2
           }
         },
         {
           loader: "postcss-loader",
           options: {
             ident: "postcss",
             plugins: () => [new PostcssPresetEnv()]
           }
         },
         {
           loader: "resolve-url-loader",
           options: { sourceMap: true }
         },
         { loader: "sass-loader", options: { sourceMap: true } } 
       ]
     },
```

Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Do you have `output.publicPath` set for production?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that `resolve-url-loader` doesn't know about the location of your final `main-output.css` and expects it to be at the roof of the `dist`.
You can try to use a custom `join` function to fix the paths:

```
{
  loader: "resolve-url-loader",
  options: {
    sourceMap: true,
    join: (uri, base) => path.join('../..', base, uri);
  }
},
```

This should output something like this:

```
background:url(../../public/images/banner-bg.jpg)
```

Haven't tested it though. Check [how-it-works](https://www.npmjs.com/package/resolve-url-loader#how-it-works) for some details. Also take a look at css-loader [url](https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-loader#function) setting.

It might be easier to change the location of `main-output.css`:

```
new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
     filename: "[name].css"
})
```

Comment: 1. join: (uri, base) => path.join('../..', base, uri); results in an error: **TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type object** I read the doc for resolve-url-loader but I don't understand it. 

2. Putting min-output.css in the root of the output folder **DOES work**  but it is an ugly solution unless I add a script to put the file back in the stylesheets folder after Webpack has completed its job.

Comment: 3. This **css-loader** solution has absolutely no impact on the image's url:
`loader: "css-loader",
options: {
  url: (url, resourcePath) => {
          if (url.includes("banner-bg.png")) {
              return false;
            }
            return true;
          },
        },`